# Push notification using Urban AirShip and Rails 3 for iphone

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

What is the best way to send push notifications through Urban AirShip using a Rails 3 web app?

From Urban Airship documentation:

> An HTTP POST to /api/push/broadcast/
>   sends the given notification to all
>   registered device tokens for the
>   application. The payload is in JSON
>   with content-type application/json,
>   with this structure:

```
{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 15,
         "alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!",
         "sound": "cat.caf"
    },
    "exclude_tokens": [
        "device token you want to skip",
        "another device token you want to skip"
    ]
}
```

I really don't know where to start!

Comment: Please, who gave me the "-1" can explain me why he did it? It would be more constructive

Comment: Well, my guess is that you got it because your question did not show any research effort. Any Google query for a combination of the words Rails, JSON, Urban Airship and POST would have given you plenty of starting points.

Comment: But it's hours I'm looking for something on the web! And there's nothing useful. Ok, if t is as simple as doing a google search... why nobody is answering?

Comment: Common dude. I got in the very first shot. Make sure to search adding github keyword too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Better way is to use [UrbanAirship Groupon version](https://github.com/groupon/urbanairship). Their docs specify every thing very clearly and it will much neater code. Worked and tested in my application.

From the read me file, (with some more comments and all):-

Note: if you are using Ruby 1.8, you should also install the system_timer gem for more reliable timeout behaviour. See http://ph7spot.com/musings/system-timer for more information. Baically

```
  gem install system_timer
```

**Installation**

```
 gem install urbanairship 
 # or specify in your gem file 
 gem "urbanairship"
```

**Configuration** define all this in initializes directory and then make sure u restart your application.

```
    Urbanairship.application_key = 'application-key'
    Urbanairship.application_secret = 'application-secret'
    Urbanairship.master_secret = 'master-secret'
    Urbanairship.logger = Rails.logger
    Urbanairship.request_timeout = 5 # default
```

**Usage**

Registering a device token

```
    Urbanairship.register_device 'DEVICE-TOKEN' # => true
```

Unregistering a device token

```
    Urbanairship.unregister_device 'DEVICE-TOKEN' # => true
```

Sending a push notification (for instant delivery remove schedule_for attribute)

```
    notification = {
      :schedule_for => 1.hour.from_now,
      :device_tokens => ['DEVICE-TOKEN-ONE', 'DEVICE-TOKEN-TWO'],
      :aps => {:alert => 'You have a new message!', :badge => 1}
    }

    Urbanairship.push notification # => true
```

Batching push notification sends (for instant delivery remove schedule_for attribute)

```
    notifications = [
      {
        :schedule_for => 1.hour.from_now,
        :device_tokens => ['DEVICE-TOKEN-ONE', 'DEVICE-TOKEN-TWO'],
        :aps => {:alert => 'You have a new message!', :badge => 1}
      },
      {
        :schedule_for => 3.hours.from_now,
        :device_tokens => ['DEVICE-TOKEN-THREE'],
        :aps => {:alert => 'You have a new message!', :badge => 1}
      }
    ]

        Urbanairship.batch_push notifications # => true
```

Sending broadcast notifications
Urbanairship allows you to send a broadcast notification to all active registered device tokens for your app.(for instant delivery remove schedule_for attribute)

```
    notification = {
      :schedule_for => 1.hour.from_now,
      :aps => {:alert => 'Important announcement!', :badge => 1}
    }

    Urbanairship.broadcast_push notification # => true
```

Comment: superb answer.. :)  well explained :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:

https://github.com/bhedana/urbanairship_on_rails

It was linked from the [Urban Airship support site](http://help.urbanairship.com/kb/push-notifications/push-server-libraries)

Comment: Ok thanks for this but I've tried it and when i start my server (rails s) it throws the following error: "/Users/abramo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/urbanairship_on_rails-0.0.1/lib/urbanairship_on_rails/models/apn/broadcast_notification.rb:18:in `<class:BroadcastNotification>': uninitialized constant APN::BroadcastNotification::AASM (NameError)
"

Comment: @Abramodj Check out the readme, make sure you have the JSON and Acts As State Machine gems instelled. Also, since this example is from 2008, I'm not sure it runs under Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Yes i have those gems installed. So what can I do? Nothing, this ?$&)£?!% airship is not working in Rails. Lot of time lost for nothing.

Comment: Urban Airship work perfectly on Rails i've realized one project based entirely on Urban Airship for an customer, you must work much harder instead wait another one work for you....

Comment: So please can you help me and tell me where to look instead? I'm working hard, but i just can't find anything to look at!

Comment: Ok, i found out i was encountering a this bug: https://github.com/geemus/fog/issues/293 . Now moved the 'pg' gem at the bottom of my gemfile and everythinkg works fine!

Comment: FYI- at the time of this comment, the last update to urbanairship_on_rails is 3yrs ago. It looks like the groupon on is maintained much more frequently (updated 2 days ago).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a simple way of sending a urban airship broadcast from ROR controller:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'open-uri'    

app_key = 'JJqr...'
app_secret = 'lAu7...'
master_secret = 'K81P...'

payload ={
    "aps" => {"badge"  => "0", "alert" => "My own message", "sound" => ""}
}.to_json

full_path = 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast/'
url = URI.parse(full_path)    
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
req.body = payload
req.basic_auth app_key, master_secret

con = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
con.use_ssl = true

r = con.start {|http| http.request(req)}

logger.info "\n\n##############\n\n  " + "Resonse body: " + r.body + "  \n\n##############\n\n"
```

Cheers!

Comment: Why is it so bad? BTW I marked your answer as the correct one!

Comment: While this is code is /terrible/, it appears to be the only way to get the request routing through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.2.x and Ruby 2.3.x, I'm using the '[urbanairship](https://github.com/urbanairship/ruby-library)' gem, it is best to reference the most recent documentation found [here](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ruby/3.2.3/push.html).

Example of sending to ios:

```
def deliver_push_notification recipient_uuid, message
  ua             = Urbanairship
  client         = ua::Client.new(key: ENV["URBAN_AIRSHIP_APP_KEY"], secret: ENV["URBAN_AIRSHIP_MASTER_SECRET"])
  p              = client.create_push
  p.audience     = ua.ios_channel(recipient_uuid)
  p.notification = ua.notification(ios: ua.ios(alert: message))
  p.device_types = ua.device_types(["ios"])
  p.send_push
end
```